# Tiling a vector in a unique way MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization, tiling, run-length-encoding

Consider `A = [ 200000 x 1]` vector. I have another vector `idx = [200000x1]`. I would like to tile `A` such that every `ith` element of A is tiled `idx(i)` times.

Eg:

```
A   idx output 
2   2    2
3   1    2
4   3    3 
5   1    4
.   .    4
.   .    4
.   .    5 
.    .     .
```

Any non-looping ideas?

Comment: Does it have to be a unique way? =P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for [run length decoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding): that is `idx(ii)` represent the *length* `A(ii)` should be present in the encoded output.

Here's a nice way of doing that in Matlab:

```
output = zeros(1, sum(idx)); % allocate output
output( cumsum( [1 idx(1:end-1)] ) ) = 1;
output = A( cumsum( output ) );

output =

 2     2     3     4     4     4     5
```